# awk geometric average on the same row value

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, mean

I have the below input and I would like to do geometric average if the “Cpd_number” and ”ID3” are the same.  The files have a lot of data so we might need arrays to do the tricks.   However, as an awk beginner, I am not very sure how to start.  Could anyone kindly offer some hints?

input:

```
“ID1”,“Cpd_number”, “ID2”,”ID3”,”activity”
“95”,“123”,”4”,”5”,”10”
“95”, “123”,”4”,”5”,”100”
“95”, “123”,”4”,”5”,”1”
“95”, “123”,”4”,”6”,”10”
“95”, “123”,”4”,”6”,”100”
“95”, “456”,”4”,”6”,”10”
“95”, “456”,”4”,”6”,”100”
```

Three lines of “95”,“123”,”4”,”5” should do a geometric average

Two lines of “95”, “123”,”4”,”6” should do a geometric average

Two lines of “95”, “456”,”4”,”6” should do a geometric average

Here is the desired output:

```
“ID1”,“Cpd_number”, “ID2”,”ID3”,”activity”
“95”,“123”,”4”,”5”,”10”
“95”, “123”,”4”,”6”,”31.62”
“95”, “456”,”4”,”6”,”31.62”
```

Some info about geometric mean:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean

This script computes a geometric mean

```
 #!/usr/bin/awk -f
 {
   b  = $1;   # value of 1st column
   C += log(b);  
   D++; 
 }

 END {
   print "Geometric mean  : ",exp(C/D);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having this file:

```
$ cat infile
"ID1","Cpd_number","ID2","ID3","activity"
"95","123","4","5","10"
"95","123","4","5","100"
"95","123","4","5","1"
"95","123","4","6","10"
"95","123","4","6","100"
"95","456","4","6","10"
"95","456","4","6","100"
```

This piece:

```
awk -F\" 'BEGIN{print}            # Print headers
      last != $4""$8 && last{     # ONLY When last key  "Cpd_number + ID3" 
          print line,exp(C/D)     # differs from actual , print line + average
          C=D=0}                  # reset acumulators
      { # This block process each line of infile
       C += log($(NF-1)+0)        # C calc
       D++                        # D counter
       $(NF-1)=""                 # Get rid of activity col ir order to print line
       line=$0                    # Line will be actual line without activity
       last=$4""$8}               # Store the key in orther to track switching 
      END{ # This block triggers after the complete file read
           # to print the last average that cannot be trigger during
           # the previous block 
          print line,exp(C/D)}' infile
```

Will throw:

```
 ID1 , Cpd_number ,  ID2 , ID3 ,   0
 95 ,  123 , 4 , 5 ,   10
 95 ,  123 , 4 , 6 ,   31.6228
 95 ,  456 , 4 , 6 ,   31.6228
```

Still some work left for formatting.

```
NOTE: char " is used  instead of “ and ”
```

**EDIT**: NF is the number of fields in file , so **NF-1** will be the next to last:

```
$ awk -F\" 'BEGIN{getline}{print $(NF-1)}' infile                                                                                 
10
100
1
10
100
10
100
```

So in: **log($(NF-1)+0)** we apply log function to that value (0 sum is added to ensure numeric value)

**D++** y just a counter.

Comment: Also, may I know what does "$8" mean here?

Comment: I have to admit, I like the awk solution.

Comment: Hi klashxx, could you kindly explain a little bit about the script?  I have a hard time fully understand it maybe because of my awk beginner level.   Also, everytime the script execute, there will be one "error" message: "awk: cmd. line:4: (FILENAME=infile FNR=10) fatal: attempt to access field -1".  May I know what this mean?

Comment: For an explanation see my edited answer @HenrySu , and about the errors you're getting.. i suspect is something related about your file format. Note: that i used char " instead of “ and ”

Comment: Thanks klashxx.  Could you also give some ideas about "C += log($(NF-1)+0) "  and "D++"?  I understand that NF = "Number of Fields in a record" but I still couldn't quite figure out what these two lines mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why use awk, just do it in bash, with either `bc` or `calc` to handle floating point math. You can download calc at http://www.isthe.com/chongo/src/calc/ (2.12.4.13-11 is latest). There are rpms, binary and source tarballs available. It is far superior to bc in my opinion. The routine is fairly simple. **You need to remove the extranious `"` quotes from your datafile** first leaving a csv file. That helps. See the `sed` command used in the comments below. Note, the geometric mean below is the 4th root of (id1*cpd*id2*id3). If you need a different mean, just adjust the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

##
##  You must strip all quotes from data before processing, or write more code to do
##  it here. Just do "$ sed -d 's/\"//g' < datafile > newdatafile" Then use 
##  newdatafile as command line argument to this program
##
##  Additionally, this script uses 'calc' for floating point math. go download it
##  from: http://www.isthe.com/chongo/src/calc/ (2.12.4.13-11 is latest). You can also
##  use bc if you like, but why, calc is so much better.
##

## test to make sure file passed as argument is readable
test -r "$1" || { echo "error: invalid input, usage: ${0//*\//} filename"; exit 1; }

## function to strip extraneous whitespace from input
trimWS() {
    [[ -z $1 ]] && return 1
    strln="${#1}"
    [[ strln -lt 2 ]] && return 1
    trimSTR=$1
    trimSTR="${trimSTR#"${trimSTR%%[![:space:]]*}"}"  # remove leading whitespace characters
    trimSTR="${trimSTR%"${trimSTR##*[![:space:]]}"}"  # remove trailing whitespace characters
    echo $trimSTR
    return 0
}

let cnt=0
let oldsum=0    # holds value to compare against new Cpd_number & ID3
product=1       # initialize product to 1
pcnt=0          # initialize the number of values in product
IFS=$',\n'      # Internal Field Separator, set to break on ',' or newline

while read newid1 newcpd newid2 newid3 newact || test -n "$act"; do

    cpd=`trimWS $cpd`  # trimWS from cpd (only one that needed it)

    # if first iteration, just output first row
    test "$cnt" -eq 0 && echo " $newid1 $newcpd $newid2 $newid3 $newact"

    # after first iteration, test oldsum -ne sum, if so do geometric mean
    # and reset product and counters
    if test "$cnt" -gt 0 ; then

        sum=$((newcpd+newid3))   # calculate sum to test against oldsum
        if test "$oldsum" -ne "$sum" && test "$cnt" -gt 1; then
            # geometric mean (nth root of product)
            # mean=`calc -p "root ($product, $pcnt)"`  # using calc
            mean=`echo "scale=6; e( l($product) / $pcnt)" | bc -l` # using bc
            echo " $id1 $cpd $id2 $id3  average: $mean"
            pcnt=0
            product=1
        fi

        # update last values to new values
        oldsum=$sum
        id1="$newid1"
        cpd="$newcpd"
        id2="$newid2"
        id3="$newid3"
        act="$newact"

        ((product*=act))  # accumulate product
        ((pcnt+=1))
    fi

    ((cnt+=1))

done < "$1"
```

output:

```
# output using calc
ID1 Cpd_number  ID2 ID3 activity
95 123 4 5  average: 10
95 123 4 6  average: 31.62277660168379331999
95 456 4 6  average: 31.62277660168379331999

# output using bc
ID1 Cpd_number  ID2 ID3 activity
95 123 4 5  average: 9.999999
95 123 4 6  average: 31.622756
95 456 4 6  average: 31.622756
```

The updated script calculates the proper mean. It is a bit more involved due to having to keep old/new values to test for the change in cpd & id3. This may be where awk is the simpler way to go. But if you need more flexibility later, bash may be the answer.

Comment: Thanks David!  May I know what does "bc" stand for?

Comment: bc is an arbitrary precision calculator language generally installed along with bash. Henry - I misunderstood which mean you wanted. The above code reads the data, but calculates the mean of the id and cpd values, instead of just the values for activity where cpd and id3 are equal. I understand what you want to do now.

Comment: @HenrySu I'm going to pull the answer and wait until I have a chance to fix the mean calculations. If you prefer I leave it, let me know, or just copy the code before I pull it down. I'll wait a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks I have copied the script!  Feel free to pull it down if you like : )

Comment: Henry, I updated the script to calculate the proper mean of activity.

Comment: Thanks David! Unfortunately I am not able to install the calc on our cluster due to restriction : (   It seems like we need to modify the script a bit so can do without "calc"

Comment: Do you have `bc` installed? All you need is an alternative that can do floating point math (multiplication and nth root to be precise). I'll check and drop a comment back.

Comment: @HenrySu The script is updated to use `bc` instead of `calc`. If you don't have `bc` on the clusters -- you are on your own :-)

Comment: Thanks man, we do have bc which is kinda default in most linux machines : )